# React + TypeScript with router deployement issue on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, github-pages

Local runs fine, but when run on "npm run deploy" the website returns 404.

I have a React + TypeScript app which utilises react-router-dom BrowserRouter to navigate between pages.

I am ware of the issue on github pages with react-router, therefore I have tried adding basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}, changing it to a HashRouter, and many many more possibilities.
I've been on this issue for 7 hours straight... and there seems to be no resources on this particular problem for Typescript.

Could someone please help me!

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AppRouter />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Router.tsx

```
export const AppRouter: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => {

return (

    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path='/' component={App} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Notes} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/About' component={About} />
            </Switch>  
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Also tried Router.tsx

```
export const AppRouter: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => {

return (

    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path='/' component={App} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Notes} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/About' component={About} />
            </Switch>  
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
);
```

NavBar.tsx

```
export const NavBar: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => {

return (
    <div id='nav-bar'>
        <AppBar position='static' color='default'>
            <Toolbar>
                <span id='navbar-title'>
                    <Typography variant='title' color='default'>
                        Keep
                    </Typography>
                </span>
                <Link to="/">
                    <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="text">Notes</Button>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/About">
                    <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="text">About</Button>
                </Link>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    </div>
)
```

Thank you for reading.

EDIT below is the exact error response from web console at 404 error. Something about favicon, could that be an issue? The location is completely wrong

```
json469.github.io/:1 Refused to load the image 'https://json469.github.io/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:".
```

I've also tried debugging by printing out the process.env.PUBLIC_URL, however it returned an empty string...

EDIT2 below is the change made to Router.tsx that fixed the issue.

```
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <NavBar />
                <main>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact={true} path='/' component={App} />
                        <Route exact={true} path='/' component={Notes} />
                        <Route exact={true} path='/About' component={About} />
                    </Switch>
                </main>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unlikely to be due to TypeScript - or even React Router. If you receive a 404, that is because your server has to redirect the user to your React app if they visit a route that the server does not know, and your app can then pretend to do actual routing.

However, it appears that GitHub Pages does not support this. Thus, you cannot do "proper" URLs like username.github.io/page/some-route. A workaround is to use the Hash Router, as you mentioned, but that means that URLs will look like username.github.io/page#/some-route.

Thus, your issue is probably that you're trying the former route, rather than the latter. So to solve it, you can either try that kind of route, or move to a different host.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the issue! I have tried HashRoute but had still no luck. Will there be anything extra that I need to change from the second Router.tsx code? As that was the HashRoute method that I have tried but still got 404 :(

Comment: @Jesse It would help if you could show us what route you tried that gets you a 404. If you use the HashRouter, at the very least you should end up in your index page, not a GitHub 404 page.

Comment: @Jesse Oh, I just saw your edit. If you only see the 404 in your console, that's because browsers automatically try to fetch /favicon.ico if none is defined - nothing to worry about. If you want to know more about that, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Now that you also posted your GitHub username, though, I can see that your app is also not located on GitHub: https://github.com/json469/json469.github.io Could you show your `package.json`, and the output when you run `npm run deploy`?

Comment: Refining the issue outside of TS was a good start for me! I've managed to start fresh and make it work with a HashRoute. I believe the fault was on me when I nested HashRoute incorrectly somehow? I've updated the change that has made it work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great to hear you solved it - sometimes it's just a matter of looking at a problem from a different angle, I guess :)